# VPN blocking selenium chromedriver's (driver service)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, block, vpn

When `VPN` is off `chromedriver` starts normally, first console app then chrome which is getting driven. But as I turn `VPN` on something is blocking it (chrome is getting blocked) with error:

```
 OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:29885/'
```

Console app of chromedriver turns on normally with message:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 120.0.6099.109 (3419140ab665596f21b385ce136419fde0924272-refs/branch-heads/6099@{#1483}) on port 58072
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

I have read all answers related to this and similar topics on stack overflow and reddit and not any solution is helping me, I have also tried to change Chrome driver to Firefox driver with no help.

OS is Windows Server 2022, Chrome is 120.0.6099.130 (Official Build) (64-bit), `Chromedriver` is 120.0.6099.109, language is C#, `VPN` is `Cyberghost 8`

Tried everything from resolutions I have found similar to this problem, but nothing is helping every time it is the same error Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:29885/' (port is random not fixed to 29885, just copied it from last error).

This is driving me nuts for 3rd day and need help if anyone have any suggestions I would appreciate it.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
```

Tried:

```
Changing Chrome and chromedriver to Firefox with geckodriver.
Fixing ports
setting no_proxy argument for localhost
setting DebuggerAddress
EnvironmentVariable no_proxy for localhost
```

Every single time the error is the same.
Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:58094/